# How to make a ListView with this border?

Tags: android, listview, border, listviewitem

I want to make a ListView like the foursquare (image below). I'm familiar with custom items.

[image]

Comment: It is really helpful for you to be familiar with `custom items`

Comment: Are you talking about the paddings???         android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"

Comment: No, I'm talking about the edges.

Comment: The Edges gray is in the item or in the ListView? How to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a layout inside of another layout in your xml. Give the outer layout a grey background, then add in padding to border of the inner layout.